# Sending email after execution of AWS cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a scenario which should do following things.

1. Create AWS Image via CLI. ( done )
2. Send Email to specific entity after AWS has created image on their side. ( I don't know how to approach this problem ).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create your own mail server or you can use AWS SES for this. In AWS SES you can verify your domain and you can use their SMTP setting to send e-mails.

Comment: @Siddharthsharma, I have email server setup, but I want send email after AMI has been created. I have limited idea on how to get status of AWS tasks.

Comment: A simple bash script will do this.

Comment: Does is have to be fully synchronous, or would it be ok to have a bit of a delay between AMI creation and the email?

Answer (score 3):

This is a pseudo code to solve this issue :-

```
recipients="user1@example.com,user2@example.com"
#Create AMI Image
aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-1e0beaaf --name "My server1" --description "An AMI for my server" &> /tmp/ami.log

# Check Exit Status
if [ $? == 0] 
then 
# Send mail if success
/usr/sbin/sendmail "$recipients" <<EOF
subject: E-mail 
from:admin@example.com
"AMI Success"
EOF

else
# Send mail if failure
/usr/sbin/sendmail "$recipients" <<EOF
subject: E-mail 
from:admin@example.com
"AMI failure"
EOF
fi
```

Edit :- Check State of AMI

```
aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-1e0beaaf --name "My server1" --description "An AMI for my server" > /tmp/ami.txt 
AMIID=`cat /tmp/ami.txt | grep ami | awk '{print $2}'`
aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids $AMIID | grep "State"
```

Edit:- You can use below script to send mail when "AMI Status = available".

```
recipients="user1@example.com,user2@example.com"
aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-1e0beaaf --name "My server" --description "An AMI for my server" > /tmp/ami.txt
AMIID=`cat /tmp/ami.txt | grep ami | awk '{print $2}'|sed 's/.//;s/.$//'`
status=`aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids $AMIID | grep "State" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/.$//' | sed 's/.//;s/.$//'`
while [ "$status" != "available" ]
do
status=`aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids $AMIID | grep "State" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/.$//'| sed 's/.//;s/.$//'`

   ##echo "$status"
sleep 5
done
echo "Sending mail"
/usr/sbin/sendmail "$recipients" <<EOF
subject: E-mail 
from:admin@example.com
"AMI Success"
EOF
```

I have tested this script and it works perfectly. It sends e-mail when AMI status is available. And the script is self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks Siddarth, but there is one problem that I found, It gives return code 0 , but still  AMI is in pending state on AWS side. Any idea ? how to get status after AMI is in available state?

Comment: yes the '0' exit status occur when above script executed without any error. If you check status of AMI it will be pending because it depends on the size of AMI to create and that task is independent of bash shell. So you cannot see the status from there. But what you can do is modify your script and check "Status" of your AMI and then send message.

Comment: Thanks Siddarth, But is there any way apart from what you mentioned , to get the status via web hooks ?.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Amazon SES and add this to your bash script.

```
#Check Exit Status
if [ $? == 0] 
then 
    aws sns publish --topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:0123456789012:my-topic" --message $SuccessMessage
else
    aws sns publish --topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:0123456789012:my-topic" --message $FailureMessage
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Vikash, but there is one problem that I found, It gives return code 0 , but still  AMI is in pending state on AWS side. Any idea ? how to get status after AMI is in available state?

Comment: You need to write a script using aws-cli which will check the status of your ami. If the status is Available then only it will send the the mail.